# Method hide does not exist on jQuery.modal fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have created an iframe using fancybox but fancybox can't hide the iframe because the following error:

```
ncaught Error: Method hide does not exist on jQuery.modal
    at Function.error (jquery.js:253)
    at jQuery.fn.init.a.fn.modal (materialize.min.js:8)
    at Q (include.js?v=9.12.1:1)
    at apply_link (include.js?v=9.12.1:1)
    at a (include.js?v=9.12.1:1)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (include.js?v=9.12.1:1)
    at HTMLUListElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4670)
    at HTMLUListElement.r.handle (jquery.js:4338)
```

I have searched other questions and I found out if I include Jquery twice, this problem occurs. So I deleted `materialize.js` and fancybox works well But I need to include materialize.js because I am using it in my ui. So How should I handle this?
I am using yii2 and this is my config:

```
public $js = [
        'js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js',
        'js/jquery.fancybox.min.js',
        'js/materialize.min.js',
        'js/script.js',
        'js/mediaelement-and-player.min.js',
        'js/flickity.pkgd.min.js',
        'js/select2.min.js',
        'js/select-category.js',
        'js/add_and_remove_text_fields.js',

        'js/iframe_upload.js'

    ];
```

This is my html code:

```
<input type="text" id="test_id" disabled>
    <a href="../filemanager/dialog.php?type=2&field_id=test_id&relative_url=1" class="btn iframe-btn"> SELECT</a>
```

and This is my JS code:

```
$('.iframe-btn').fancybox({
    'width'     : 900,
    'height'    : 600,
    'type'      : 'iframe',
    'autoScale'     : false
});
```

Comment: Show us the code.

Comment: I do not see any issue when combining fancyBox and materialize, also, that message "Method hide does not exist on jQuery.modal" does not seem to be related to the fancyBox.